# $http complete function using $q

Tags: angularjs

I want to use something in angularjs using deferred promise. so that I can use then condition when my $http request is done. I tried it with finally but code is not valid and always didnt work after the error block.

```
userApp.runMachineLearning = function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $route, $q) {
$scope.objRun = {};
$scope.loader = {
    loading : false
};

deferred=$q.defer();

$scope.runMachine = function(objRun) {

    $scope.loader.loading = true;


        $scope.objRun = objRun;
        $scope.method = 'POST';
        console.log("Call");

        $scope.url = 'rest/service/pipeline/runMachineLearning';

        $http({
            method : $scope.method,
            url : $scope.url,
            data : $scope.objRun,
            headers : {
                'X-Auth-Token' : $rootScope.authToken
            }
        }).success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.status = status;
            $scope.data = data;
        }).error(function(data, status) {
            $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
            $scope.status = status;
        }).then(function(data) {
          console.log("Complete Message");
        });

};
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mis-using the promise object returned by $http service.
You didn't use your deffered object and seems like you don't need to, first lets look at the way you should be using $http promise.

When you are getting a promise, you have 2 ways to handle it:

1. Regular then method - then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback)

   > ```
   > promise.then(function(greeting) {
   >   alert('Success: ' + greeting);
   > }, function(reason) {
   >   alert('Failed: ' + reason);
   > });
   > ```
2. Success\Error

   > ```
   > $http.post('/someUrl', {msg:'hello word!'}).
   > success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   >     // this callback will be called asynchronously
   >     // when the response is available
   >   }).
   >   error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   >     // called asynchronously if an error occurs
   >     // or server returns response with an error status.
   >   });
   > ```

In your case you used both + didn't use then properly.
Here is angularjs documentation for [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) and [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to separate your controllers and your services. A controller merely sets up the view-model that your view gets attached to. A service is something that carries out http calls and applies business logic to data.

If I were to write out your implementation using controllers and services it would roughly look like this:

```
angular.module('machineLearning', [])
  .factory('authService', ['$rootScope', authService])
  .factory('runMachineLearningService', ['$http', 'authService', runMachineLearningService])
  .controller('runMachineLearningCtrl', ['$scope', 'runMachineLearningService', runMachineLearningCtrl])

function authService() {
  var service = {
    getAuthToken: getAuthToken
  };

  return service;

  function getAuthToken(){
    // some implementation that returns the auth token
  }
}

function runMachineLearningService($http, authService){
  var service = {
    run: run
  };

  var serviceBase = 'rest/service/pipeline/runMachineLearning';

  return service;

  function run(objRun){
    return $http.post(serviceBase, objRun, {
        headers : {
            'X-Auth-Token': authService.getAuthToken
        }
    }).then(function (data) {
      return data.data;
    }).catch(function (message) {
      // do something with this error.
    });
  }
}

function runMachineLearningCtrl($scope, runMachineLearningService) {
  $scope.objRun = {};
  $scope.loader = {
      loading : false
  };

  $scope.runMachine = function(objRun) {
    runMachineLearningService.run(objRun)
      .success(function(data, status) {
          $scope.status = status;
          $scope.data = data;
      }).error(function(data, status) {
          $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
          $scope.status = status;
      }).then(function(data) {
        console.log("Complete Message");
      });

  };
}
```

The advantages of doing this are:

- Good level of separation of concerns
- Minimizes the size of you dependency chain passed to your controller
- Easier to maintain

All these are good things that help maintaining and/or debugging your angular code base easier and better.

Some things to note in my code:

- `$http` is returned from the service, and the `then` function can be accessed multiple times, this allows you to create a pipeline of promises, each can modify your data along the way. It allows you to use error logging and normal logging services inside the service keeping them out of your controller
- `AuthService` is abstracting the authorisation logic from everything, therefore making it reusable around the rest of your application
- In the controller it is a lot easier to see what is going on because the code isn't polluted with `auth` boilerplate or `$http` boilerplate code.

As for understanding the `$q` library and `$http` its good to start with what they are.

- `$q` is an implementation to help with asynchronous callbacks, it provides you with a promise that can be resolved or rejected at some point in the future. When this promise is returned, it exposes some functions that will execute when it has been resolved or rejected.
- `$http` is a service that makes it easier to make AJAX calls and **implements** `$q`

This means, you do not need to use `$q` with `$http` in order to make use of the asynchronicity of AJAX calls.